# File "/usr/bin/sdkmanager", line 33, in <module> sys.exit(load_entry_point('sdkmanager==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'sdkmanager')())

Tags: ubuntu, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager, command-line-tool

I have installed `android-sdk` then `sdkmanager` both using `sudo apt install ...` command and the result for `sdkmanager --version` is as following:

`25.2.0`

But when I try `sdkmanager --update` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sdkmanager", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('sdkmanager==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'sdkmanager')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 1074, in main
    raise NotImplementedError('Command "--%s" not implemented' % command)
NotImplementedError: Command "--update" not implemented
```

Also similar results for other commands like `--install`. What is the problem?